# Null reference exception on c# grpc request

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

As the title described, I'm having a problem with this proto message:

(Proto file)

```
message StreamingRecognizeRequest{
  oneof streaming_request{
    StreamingRecognitionConfig streaming_config = 1;
    bytes audio_content = 2;
  }
}
```

Here is how I called it:
(C# main function)

```
await voice.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new StreamingRecognizeRequest
            {

                StreamingConfig =
                {
                    SingleUtterance = true,
                    InterimResults = true,
                    Config =
                    {
                        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                        MaxAlternatives = 1,
                        SampleRateHertz = 8000,
                        Enhanced = true,
                        SpeechContexts =
                        {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

But the debugger keep marking my Stream Recognize Reuqest as **null reference exception**, the same pattern works fine in NodeJS but I only have this error in C#. Note that the first message send to the gRPC server doesn't require "Audio Content". So what is the root cause of this error and how to solve it? Or this is gRPC bug on c#?
Thank you!

Comment: Obviously the `StreamingRecognizeRequest` isn't null, you're instantiating a new one right there, which means something else on that line is throwing the exception, my guess is that `voice.RequestStream` is null, but I can't know for sure, only you can. Set a breakpoint on that line and inspect the variables/ properties you're accessing to see whether any of them are null

Comment: did you check if `voice` is null? or Anything from `RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16` is null?

Comment: @Chetan that does look like namespaces `RecognitionConfig.Types` of an enumeration called `AudioEncoding` and the enumeration value `Linear16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty funny how I fixed it. Just not putting them inside each other but seperately create new object:

```
    RecognitionConfig regcfg = new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                MaxAlternatives = 1,
                SampleRateHertz = 8000,
                Enhanced = true,
            };

            StreamingRecognitionConfig stc = new StreamingRecognitionConfig
            {
                Config = regcfg,
                SingleUtterance = true,
                InterimResults = true,
            };

            //Create new gRPC stream listener
            var voice = vaisclient.StreamingRecognize(meta);
            await voice.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new StreamingRecognizeRequest
            {
                StreamingConfig = stc
            }) ;
```